# Status of "Reviews Completed" in a springer journal

Tags: publications, journal-workflow

We had submitted to a springer journal (field: Bioinformatics). Two reviewers reviewed the paper and both strongly and unequivocally recommended publication after a few minor changes, e.g., grammatical, a few small clarifications and change of background colors (from black to white for printing purposes). The editor seemed to be very happy about the reviews as well. However, in the tracking site it displayed 'Major Revision' probably as a norm - though frankly there was nothing major in the suggested revisions and both reviewers actually used the term 'minor' in their reports ! It took us no more than two days to do all suggested changes and resubmit. The second round of review has now taken little more than a month, out of which the status was 'under review' for last two weeks and 'Reviews Completed' from last two days. I have never encountered this status before elsewhere so wonder what it means ! Is it similar to 'Pending decision' or indicative of something more than that ? This is my first communication as a corresponding author, so, not to mention, am a bit tensed.

Comment: If people start sending e-mails to someone@springer.com instead of posting questions here, there are chances that they eventually figure out that their user interface is lacking and poorly documented, and that they decide that it costs them less money to change it rather than to answer a constant stream of support questions.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni I want to be able to give more upvote for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This means that in the next couple of days or so you will hear from the editor for the decision on your manuscript. Basically it means what it says: the journal has received the reviews, the editor is reading them and preparing the letter with her/his decision to send you.